# Multiple Tableau users connected to Hive LLAP

Tags: hive, tableau-api, business-intelligence, amazon-emr, data-lake

I’m hoping to allow interactive queries for many Tableau users with data accessed via Hive LLAP. So far results have disappointed.... should I expect this setup to work for me or should I use a different backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same approach in our project but not very fruitful.

2 options I would suggest:

1. Double the nodes for `LLAP` server if possible.
2. Use `Snowflake database` - Copy your hive tables to `Snowflake` and expose `Snowflake` to Tableau.

Unfortunately, both the suggestion incur a good cost. :( 
but I am saying this from my experience!

Comment: Thanks, Sagar. Due to non-technical restrictions, Snowflake won’t work as an option in this case. Do you have rough sense of the generic performance improvements in increasing the LLAP nodes? I can justify the cost if the performance meets our target.

Comment: So it's straightforward, More LLAP nodes, more RAM, more power to your queries.As you mentioned there are multiple users firing queries, LLAP performance will definitely get impacted. So with more power what will happen is, If currently a query is taking say 1 minute to fetch the output, with more nodes it may come down to 20-30 secs So overall LLAP query performance would be better and your tableau team would be relatively Happy. Also, make sure you have separate nodes for your day to day ETL load and LLAP. Don't combine them at any cost.